# After installing SSL through cpanel in shared hosting I get warnings and errors with subdomains and SMTP without SSL or TLS

Tags: https, cpanel, shared-hosting

I manage my wordpress site that is hosted in a shared hosting plan, but I am not a web developer. A couple of days ago, I purchased an SSL and migrated from http to https with the help of a wordpress plugin called "Really Simple SSL". I don't think I messed anything up. However some things seem odd.

For example in cpanel, under SSL/TLS tab and when clicking "Manage SSL Sites", I get this status:

[image: SSL/TLS > Manage SSL Sites, screenshot]

As a result I get warnings when running a test with htbridge.com about the SSL setup:

[image: htbridge.com SSL, screenshot]

I am not sure, but I think these domains where protected before the installation of the new SSL. Am I supposed to not worry about these domains not having the green lock protection sign? Should I fix it somehow, and if yes what am I supposed to do?

For the installation of the SSL I followed this guide: [Installing a SSL certificate on your server, using cPanel](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9418//installing-a-ssl-certificate-on-your-server-using-cpanel)